# Recursive overload method with derived parameter

Tags: c#, recursion, overloading

Can anyone explain how which overloaded method is chosen when options only differ by a parameter type being derived?
For example, the following code:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void LogException(AggregateException aggrException, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Inner exceptions on following logs.\n (Type: {1}); (Message: {2})", message, aggrException.GetType(), aggrException.Message, aggrException.StackTrace));
        foreach (var ie in aggrException.InnerExceptions)
            LogException(ie, "Inner Exception.");
    }

    public static void LogException(Exception exception, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\n (Type: {1}); (Message: {2})", message, exception.GetType(), exception.Message, exception.StackTrace));
        if (exception.InnerException != null)
            LogException(exception.InnerException, "Inner Exception.");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var invadidOpExcep1 = new InvalidOperationException("%INVALID_OP1%");
        LogException(invadidOpExcep1, "LOG1");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        var argumentExcep1 = new ArgumentException("%ARGUMENT1%");
        LogException(argumentExcep1, "LOG2");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        var aggregateExcep1 = new AggregateException("%AGGREGATE1%", invadidOpExcep1, argumentExcep1);
        LogException(aggregateExcep1, "LOG3");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        var indORExcep1 = new IndexOutOfRangeException("%INDOR1%");
        var aggregateExcep2 = new AggregateException("%AGGREGATE2%", aggregateExcep1, indORExcep1);
        LogException(aggregateExcep2, "LOG4");
    }
}
```

... produces the following output:

```
LOG1
 (Type: System.InvalidOperationException); (Message: %INVALID_OP1%)
------------------------------------------------
LOG2
 (Type: System.ArgumentException); (Message: %ARGUMENT1%)
------------------------------------------------
LOG3 Inner exceptions on following logs.
 (Type: System.AggregateException); (Message: %AGGREGATE1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.InvalidOperationException); (Message: %INVALID_OP1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.ArgumentException); (Message: %ARGUMENT1%)
------------------------------------------------
LOG4 Inner exceptions on following logs.
 (Type: System.AggregateException); (Message: %AGGREGATE2%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.AggregateException); (Message: %AGGREGATE1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.InvalidOperationException); (Message: %INVALID_OP1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException); (Message: %INDOR1%)
```

Logs 1 through 3 are fine. In the first two, `InvalidOperationException` and `ArgumentException` are both `Exception`s and are not `AggregateException`s, so the `LogException` that takes an `Exception` is called. In the third one, an `AggregateException` is being passed, so the overload that takes that type as a parameter is called.
But on Log 4, passing an `AggregateException` that has another `AggregateException` 'inside', I expected it to call the `AggregateException` overload twice, meaning, I expected the 4th log to be:

```
LOG4 Inner exceptions on following logs.
 (Type: System.AggregateException); (Message: %AGGREGATE2%)
Inner Exception. Inner exceptions on following logs.
 (Type: System.AggregateException); (Message: %AGGREGATE1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.InvalidOperationException); (Message: %INVALID_OP1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.ArgumentException); (Message: %ARGUMENT1%)
Inner Exception.
 (Type: System.IndexOutOfRangeException); (Message: %INDOR1%)
```

Can anyone shed some light onto what's goin on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The method is called according to the compile-time type. You seem to actually want to know how you can bypass that behavior. See marked duplicate. Alternatively, you might find that making the type of `ie` in the `foreach` loop `dynamic` would also produce the effect you want.

Comment: 'Fun' fact, if I was running this on .NET Core (3.1, at least), I wouldn't need this code, because `AggregateException.Message` already includes all of its `InnerExceptions`' messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AggregateException.InnerExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions?view=netframework-4.8#System_AggregateException_InnerExceptions) is of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Exception>`. This means your foreach variable `ie` is of type `Exception`. Because the call of `LogException` is statically dispatched (at compile-time), the compiler chooses the overload with the `Exception` signature.

Comment: This is why I highly recommend to explicitly specify variable types, and never use the `var` keyword.

Comment: Up until now, I always had the opinion that `var`was better because it was 'cleaner'. But, yeah, I guess I got to stop using it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Method calls are resolved in compile time. On Log 4, you pass an `AggregateException`, and as you expected, `LogException(AggregateException, string)` is called.

Then, `LogException` is called on the result of [`InnerException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.innerexception?view=netframework-4.8) is called. `InnerException` returns an `Exception`, so `LogException(Exception, string)` is called. The runtime type that's actually returned is inconsequential since the resolution is done in compile time.

Comment: Thanks, for answering. I would've accepted your answer, if Emanuel hadn't answered first.